# Can you overlay a transparent css3 gradient over a background image?

Tags: css, gradient, mask

I'm trying to put a css3 gradient over the top of a background image. Using the code below puts a background image on top of my gradient, but i'm trying to do it the other way around, so the gradient acts as a mask on top.

```
url(images/darkwood.png),
-webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#EEF), to(#000)) 300px 50px no-repeat,
-webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#EFE), to(#000)) 0 0 no-repeat;
background: 
url(images/darkwood.png),
-moz-linear-gradient(#EEF, rgba(0,0,0,1)) 300px 50px no-repeat, 
-moz-linear-gradient(#EFE, rgba(0,0,0,1)) 0 0 no-repeat;
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you make a [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) of what you have so far? You can upload the image [here](http://imgur.com/).

Answer (score 51):

I have do this for one of my website, Hope it's work for you;

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUsp6.jpg') repeat;
}

body:before {
 content: " ";
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: -1;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 background: -webkit-radial-gradient(top center, ellipse cover, rgba(255,255,255,0.2) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 100%);
}
```

Comment: I have been looking for something that does this for a very long time. The only change I made was `position: fixed`.

Answer (score 18):

The example [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8049370) won't work with resizeable divs.

Your code would work fine. But as I understand it, CSS reads from the right to the left.
So you would have to use the following:

```
div {
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(top center, ellipse cover, rgba(255,255,255,0.2) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 100%), url('http://www.google.co.uk/logos/classicplus.png') repeat;
}
```

Example:
http://sapphion.com/2011/11/css3-background-gradient-on-top-of-an-image/

Answer (score 0):

It may be help you:

```
yourselector {
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(0,130,170,0),rgba(0,130,170,1)), url('/path/image.jpg');
}
```

For more gradient style visit: https://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/