# smoothing out transition between blackish image and black background

Tags: html, css

With the following CSS:

```
#divPic {
  height: 32pc; 
  background-image:  url('https://wallpaperscraft.com/image/black_black_white_bone_time_game_noise_74543_4000x2248.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left center;
  background-color: #000000;
  opacity: 1;

}
```

... I set the image dice.jpg as the background-image of the div with id divPic.

The result is this:

[image]

The problem is that the picture doesn't cover the whole range of the frame.

If I change the background-color to blue, you can see which part is covered by the image and which part is not:

[image]

I am using background-color black (#000000), so it looks more or less ok but what is annoying me is that, if you look closely, you see the right edge of the image ... i.e. the background-color (#000000) and the color of the image (some slightly different black) do not match perfectly. I tried experimenting with different kind of black (e.g. #000008 instead of #000000, etc.) but you could still see the edge where the image ends and the background-color begins.

My question is therefore: is there some way to smooth out the transition between the image and the background-color so that you don't see the edge anymore?

*************************************UPADTE*********************************

Here's some context:

I'm using bootstrap, the frame for the picture is a bootstrap-column:

```
       <div id="picContainer" class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 thumbnail" id="divPic"></div>
            <div class="col-xs-12" id="button_div"></div> 
       </div>
```

Comment: thank you, thought this was not possible ... updated the question with the link you provided

Comment: No problem, it's not straightforward to get the direct link. I deleted the now irrelevant comments. Can you please add the contextual markup for your div(html and other relevant classes)?

Comment: Try this https://jsfiddle.net/jbzzogpq/ just focus on the box-shadow property.

Comment: Thank you very much! That worked!

Answer (score 2):

I don't have enough reputation to make a comment, but have you tried using either `#010101` or `#020202` as background colors?  This is the color of the image at the edge, so choosing either of these will make it look as smooth as possible without needing to apply a transparency gradient to the image or what-have-you.

UPDATE:

If you need an actually smooth transition, you can apply a CSS3 gradient on top of the background image to transition into the color you want.  The following JSFiddle has an example of this, using the code below: https://jsfiddle.net/Auroratide/7j8c0v1k/

```
#divPic {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(2, 2, 2, 0) 300px, rgba(2, 2, 2, 1) 400px), url('https://wallpaperscraft.com/image/black_black_white_bone_time_game_noise_74543_4000x2248.jpg');
}
```

I used [this Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15814346/is-it-possible-to-use-css-to-make-a-background-image-fade-or-gradient-the-bott) answer as reference.

Comment: I can still see the edge though

Comment: You can also try the following JSFiddle where a transparent gradient is applied on top of the image: https://jsfiddle.net/Auroratide/7j8c0v1k/