# How can I implement a "see more" button on a div with set height, but very large content?

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular-material

I'm sure this has been asked many times before, but I'm having difficulty wording this in a way that gets me results. I have also found very outdated answers (8+ years ago), and they seemed too complicated considering the technology we have today.The modern solutions I've found work specifically with text, by using things like `-webkit-line-clamp`

This project uses Angular, Angular Material, and Sass, so I'm sure there is an elegant way to achieve this. I just need to implement something like the image below:

[image]

The content shown inside will be a bar chart, but I don't think this makes much of a difference.

Again, I'm sorry for asking a, no doubt, extremely repeated question, but I just haven't found any answers or tutorials. A suggestion for search terms would already help me a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said its been answered many times, so please upvote this [`answer from Design.Garden`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15814346/is-it-possible-to-use-css-to-make-a-background-image-fade-or-gradient-the-bott)

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  template: `
    <div [ngClass]="{'fade': showFade, 'image': true}">
      <span *ngIf="showFade" class="show-fade" (click)="showFade = !showFade"> show more!</span>
</div>
  `,
  styles: [
    `
    :host {
      display: block;
      height:100%;
    }
    .image::before {
      
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-image: url('https://placehold.co/500X600');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    }
    .fade {
      height:100%;
      display: flex;
      align-items: end;
      justify-content: center;
    }
    .show-fade {
      z-index: 1;
      margin-bottom:100px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    .fade::before {
      -webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, white 60%, transparent 80%);
    }
  `,
  ],
})
export class App {
  showFade = true;
  name = 'Angular';
}

bootstrapApplication(App);
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-hnsubx?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Fglobal_styles.css,src%2Findex.html&title=Angular%20Starter)

Comment: Why are you setting the fade color to black in the linear gradient?

Comment: I couldn't adapt your answer to my situation with the graph, but it does work for images which I think is very valuable for people who may find this issue in the future.

Comment: @Tuma if you are having issues please raise a question with a stackblitz will check it!

Comment: thanks so much for trying to help me. I need to put an ApexChart inside the "show more", like this. https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-pvlpou?file=src%2Fmain.ts.

Comment: @Tuma here you go [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-5c7ppf?file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Findex.html,src%2Fglobal_styles.css) do raise a new question I will answer it!

Answer (score 1):

You can get it only with a variable

```
more:boolean=false;

<div [style.max-height.px]=more?50:null>
    ..your image..
</div>
<button (click)="more=!more">{{more?'show less':'show more'}}</button>
```

well, you can create a component, or a directive with this idea, but it's only change the style.max-height binding with a variable.

**Update**, adding transition and a bit of css

As to animation max-height we need give the dimension we can use a template reference variable to the image and use offsetHeight to get the dimension.

Here the .html

```
<div class="wrapper" [style.max-height.px]="more?100:(img.offsetHeight||null)">
  <div class="bottom">
    <button (click)="more=!more">{{more?'show more':'show less'}}</button>
  </div>
  <img #img src="https://picsum.photos/300/300?random=1" />
</div>
```

The .css (explain in comments)

```
  .wrapper{
    overflow:hidden;  /*no show scroll bars*/
    width:fit-content;   /*the width adapt to the inner content*/
    position:relative;
    transition: max-height .5s ease-out;  /*a simple transaction*/
  }
   
  .bottom{  /*is the div where the button is*/
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;  
    display:flex;   /*to center we use flex-box*/
    justify-content: center;
    padding:.5rem 0;
                    /*Made a background with a linear gradient
                      top to bottom make a little fade*/
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, 
                                      rgba(255,255,255,0), 
                                      rgba(255,255,255,1), 
                                      rgba(255,255,255,1));
  }
   /*simple button*/
  .bottom button{
    display:inline-block;
    padding:8px 16px;
    background-color:transparent;
    border:none;
  }
```

a little [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-knsakg?file=src%2Fmain.ts)